# Adding a row with a colums to be a combination of two other cells in sql servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am not sure if asking it right.

Is it possible to have rows in sql tables where some values can be a combination of a particular cell in a row , similar to excel ?

E.g)

---

> ID(string)  | Name(string)

---

> 1 | Xyx

---

> 2 | yzw

---

> 3  | Combine Name from table where Id is 1 and Id is 2

---

### Use Case:

We use the database values for a list box. We want a way so allow multiple selections in list box, but our vendor front endt does not allow multi selection list boxes and we were trying to combine values. The ID will be the display string. So I am trying to accomplish something like `Select All` as option

From what I searched trigger is the way to go? or are there some other ways to go about it? dont think values can be variable types.

Comment: You don't want to make this data a part of the table though...you need to give some more info on your use case.

Comment: I also think a trigger is the way to go- there is no way to do this in the table definition as far as I know. Make the trigger so that upon inserting or updating the table, it updates the column with the combined values. (Creating a View could also handle this for you, but it sounds like you want it in the table).

Comment: Is the third row supposed to be `3|Xyxyzw`?

Comment: @JNK I have updated it..

Comment: @DMason yes its something like 3|Xyxyzw

Comment: This seems like a lot of unnecessary gymnastics to get around not using a multi-select list box.  Who is the vendor?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only alternative is to change our input from list box to multiple radio buttons or build an external customized pop up window which will be significantly different for users just to add `select all` options. Thats why I am investigating if this is a good choice or not.

Comment: So let's say you have `Id 1, Id 2, Id 3 ... Id n` in your table.  Would an "All of the above" row for `Id n+1` be appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are not able to write your SQL query in such a way as to concatenate the columns manually? Like, you are using some sort of front-end tool that automatically maps the drop-down contents to a single database column?

If that is the case, then you may want to look at defining a computed column for the "combined value" that you want. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: It was an old code Where have some common functions already written and used across. So I was just curious to see if there is some options such as this before I touch the old dlls in use. Could be a bad choice but thought its worth knowing. Thanks for the link